# Is possible sending emails without knowing the password?

Tags: emails

My customer purchased hosting and email accounts (info@mycompany.com) at hostgator. The new project that I have to upload to his hostgator is sending emails from info@mycompany.com.

The question: can send those emails without knowing the password since he doesn't want to tell me the password?

He argues that there is currently a hosted project which is sending emails without knowing the password. I could not believe that, so I have checked the current project's config file and found this:

```
public $display_offline_message = '1';
public $offline_image = '';
public $sitename = ' My Company';
public $editor = 'tinymce';
public $captcha = 'recaptcha';
public $list_limit = '20';
public $access = '1';
public $debug = '0';
public $debug_lang = '0';
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = '*******';
public $password = '*******';
public $db = '*******';
public $dbprefix = '*****_';
public $live_site = '';
public $secret = 'fasdfadfsf';
public $gzip = '0';
public $error_reporting = 'default';
public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
public $ftp_host = '127.0.0.1';
public $ftp_port = '21';
public $ftp_user = 'admin';
public $ftp_pass = '*****';
public $ftp_root = '';
public $ftp_enable = '0';
public $offset = 'Europe/Madrid';
public $mailer = 'mail';
public $mailfrom = 'contacto@mycompany.com';
public $fromname = 'My Company';
public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
public $smtpauth = '0';
public $smtpuser = '';
public $smtppass = '';  <<<<< I expected the password here
public $smtphost = 'localhost';
public $smtpsecure = 'none';
public $smtpport = '25';
public $caching = '0';
public $cache_handler = 'file';
public $cachetime = '15';
public $MetaDesc = '';
```

So is it true the current project doesn't know the password? Or if the password maybe written in another file?

Comment: What your customer wants is at least strange to say nothing else ... If you have access to the hosting source code can easily know the password even though it was written in another file ....

Comment: @Max yes maybe.. but my question is now: where is the password to send emails?

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying *how* you intend to send these emails, but by default, Joomla uses PHP to send emails, and does not require any additional password. I don't know about the technical details with this, but using a Joomla component (like AcyMailing or JNews) does not require any password other than the regular admin login.

You can set the email options under **Global configuration** -> **Server** tab from your Joomla admin area.

[image]

The lines from your `configuration.php` that you mention are used only if you set "SMTP" as mailer. Otherwise, they are ignored.

```
public $smtpauth = '0';
public $smtpuser = '';
public $smtppass = '';  <<<<< I expected the password here
public $smtphost = 'localhost';
public $smtpsecure = 'none';
public $smtpport = '25';
```

Hence, you don't need the password for `info@mycompany.com` in order to send emails from that account using Joomla.